# Offline Installation of Chrome: target doesn't exist

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I recently downloaded Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. After extraction, `google-chrome-stable` (from `chrome->usr->bin->...`) says

```
the link "google-chrome-stable" is broken and its target "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome" doesn't exist ...
```

What should I do?

Comment: Could you add the download link you used and how exactly you attempted to install it, please? If it was a `*.deb` file you downloaded, you may not extract it, but install it using the terminal (open with CTRL+ALT+T) command `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/file.deb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always install `.deb` files by opening a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/file.deb
```

For example:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/google-chrome-stable.deb
```

You should **never** just extract the binary files from the archive and try to run them. This may work for very simple applications, but is usually predetermined to fail.

Or, whenever possible, use the **Ubuntu Software Center** to download and install software without any trouble.

Comment: :: you've made my day bro . but previously I downloaded opera.deb,extracted it,opera-stable->usr->bin->opera(LinkToExecutable(application/x-executable)) ->double click -> opera ran !!!! no installation !!! N.B: chrome icon is (LinkToShellScript(application/x-shellscript))

Comment: If for some reason you need to download a .deb, you want to use the package manager to install it as in the answer. There are indeed some programs where the binary will run without formal installation, but it's not common and you're setting yourself up for potential problems down the road. If a binary doesn't need to be installed to run (eclipse, for example), it's usually distributed in some type of zipped file, which you can just extract, rather than a .deb.